# How to send messages using WhatsApp API properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, whatsapp

I would like to implement notifications through WhatsApp API into my app. I've done lots of research but I couldn't find anything official.

Officially WhatsApp API Bussiness exists, but it is a beta version and only for companies that send massive volume of messages (1 million+). There is also Twilio, it requires a business approval and I got denied because (again) my volume requirement isn't into the millions of messages per month.

Unofficial libraries exist that potentially could get the job done. I looked into it and the one that I was contemplating seemed to be unreliable. But is this really the only way?

Since the start of pandemic I've been receiving all sorts of ads with apps that offer WhatsApp notification for orders and customer services... how are they doing it? I know they are small businesses, so there must be a way.

My app was built using JavaScript/React, any information is appreciated.

Comment: _“I know they are small businesses”_ - so what, that doesn’t mean that they are not probably using a service provided by one of those companies that _do_ have access to the API.

Comment: @CBroe, which companies allow small volume of messages? That's what I want to know.

Comment: _That_ would rather be an off-topic question here to begin with. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, item 4)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is this-
[These provide APIs that you](https://www.facebook.com/business/partner-directory/search?platforms=whatsapp&solution_type=messaging&sort_by=alpha) can use in your App. 
Moreover WhatsApp will terminate your account if you use tools other than officials ones.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but have used this for other web related tasks. Since WebWhatsApp runs in the browser on a PC, a VERY hacky way of doing this *might* (using a normal account) be as follows:

- Web WhatsApp on the browser.
- Selenium plug-in for the browser.
- Java/C# or other programming language with Selenium libraries.

Then:

- Record a macro in Selenium of your typical WhatsApp message (Search for contact, select contact, type message, send).
- Manipulate the macro in C#/Java.

For anyone with time it's worth a try.